# Autodesk Forge Viewer, Search

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am using Autodesk Forge Viewer.

```
viewer.search('"' + keyword +'"', function(e)
{
    viewer.select(e);
    viewer.fitToView(e);
}
```

I am searching like this.
The problem is that it searches for both "SG-100" and "SSG-100".
I only want to search for SG-100.

How can I do this?
Help!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to do a second filter inside the search:

```
viewer.search(keyword, (dbIds) => {
   // success
   viewer.getBulkProperties(dbIds, ['AttributeName'], (elements) => {
      let dbIdsToSelect = [];
      for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
         if (elements[i].properties[0].displayValue===keyword)
            dbIdsToSelect.push(elements[i].dbId;
      }

      viewer.select(dbIdsToSelect);
      viewer.fitToView(dbIdsToSelect);
   }
}, (e) => {
   // error, handle here...
}, ['AttributeName']);
```

Comment: What is "  ['AttributeName']  "?

Comment: Its an array of strings that tell the function which attributes of a dbid it needs to retrieve. This should match the property you are searching for. Ie the property that equals to  "SSG-100" in your case.

Comment: thank!
But I got this error.
"Uncaught TypeError: viewer.getBulkProperties is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Augusto's suggestion that you'd need to limit the search scope to specific properties only to avoid partial matches. According to the `search` function description it's supposed to do just that if you provide the list of property names in the 4th argument that is called '`attributeNames`'. Unfortunately, from my experience, that does not work, so you need a second level filtering by using a `getBulkProperties` function that will reduce the list of dbIds from the search to only those that have specific properties defined. Pay attention, that the `search` method belong to the `viewer` object but the `getBulkProperties` method belongs to the `viewer.model` object.